# get max value from datatables

Tags: javascript, datatables

I would like to ask for ideas on how to get the max number from a specific column and return an icon on a different column.
I'm using rowCallback, so if there is a maximum number the status will change to active(check mark) and the rest will be x mark.

Here's my desired output:
[image]

Here's my code:

```
"rowCallback": function(row, data, num ) {
      
        if(parseInt(data["num"]) === max ){
            $('td:eq(3)', row).html('<a class="btn btn-link btn-success btn-just-icon btn-round"><i class="material-icons">check</i>');
        }
        else{
            $('td:eq(3)',row).html('<a class="btn btn-link btn-danger btn-just-icon btn-round"><i class="material-icons">highlight_off</i>');
            
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Ideally (if you have access to the data before the HTML is generated) you would compute the maximum value of that column once and pass it to the script.
2. If you can't do that and need to stay in JS, then the DataTables API has a [.column](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().data())-method that you can use to extract the data. So you can do something like this:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();  // adjust a neccessary to get your table
 
    var max = table
        .column( 2 )
        .data()
        .reduce( function (a,b) {
            return Math.max(a,b);
        } );
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Can you show me how to implement this?
I prefer option 2. Sorry really lost right now, first time doing this kind of implementation on a page. So do I add it inside my rowcallBack?
like this?

"rowCallback": function(row, data, num ) {
      var max = table1
            .column(2)
            .data()
            .reduce( function (a,b) {
            return Math.max(a,b);
        } );
        if(parseInt(data["num"]) === max ){

        }
        else{      
        }
    },

Comment: Sure, I'd be happy to help you get this working - but you didn't provide much info to help with that ;)  Your code looks code - but possibly `column(2)` needs to be adjusted - this assumes that the 3d columns has the data we're interested in. It's a 0-based index, so check if that does need an update (as I think it will)...

Comment: I have figured it out. I will post my answer later